# Why doesn't "a && (b = 5/a)" assign "5/a" to "b"?

Tags: c, debugging, boolean, variable-assignment, unsigned

Does `a && (b = 5/a)` assign `5/a` to `b` (for nonzero `a`)?

My friend says it doesn't, but I'm confused why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your friend is wrong. For nonzero `a`, the statement `a && (b = 5/a)` will assign the value `5/a` to `b`.

If `a == 0`, then the conditional will short circuit and the assignment will not occur.

Comment: Gotta love stupid answers like this... dunno why they get so many upvotes but it's awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

Your friend is wrong.  Both sides must be evaluated if `a` evaluates to true because `&&` must evaluate both sides in order to perform the correct action.  `||` on the other hand would not.  You could have easily tested this yourself of course simply by executing the code and checking the value of `b` after the conditional.

Comment: The conditional will short circuit if `a == 0`... no error will occur :).

Comment: @AlexLockwood: It is stated in the question that `a` is assumed to evaluate to true, but I added that regardless since it is probably better to note it than ignore it.

Comment: @AlexLockwood: Oh, you know what; I somehow missed the fact that `a` is the same variable being used before the `&&`.  I (for whatever reason) didn't catch that and focused on the `a` in the division, but not in the first part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the evaluation will break away early if it makes sense from a logic reduction standpoint.

ie:

```
if(a && (b=5/a))
```

If a is zero, then logically, the whole statement is zero/false, if you ignore system errors (ie: divide by zero), so the rest of the statement won't be evaluated (eg: "zero and anything equals zero", so why bother calculating the "and anything" portion when we already know the final answer will always be zero).

A better solution would be:

```
if(a) {
  b=5/a;
} else {
  b=0;
  printf("ERROR! Attempt to divide by zero would have happened here!");
if(a && b) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is incorrect. Given that a and b are ints then when a is zero
b is left untouched but when a is zero then 5 is divided by a(int division!) ...

The '&&' operator is a short circuit evaluation...

Checked this out using gcc...